# JQuery validation not working on webmatrix when locally hosting?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate, webmatrix

Ok so I know it validates correctly as it works in JSfiddle, but when I try to run it locally for some reason it is not validating. I have nothing happening with the POST of the form yet. Also, I am using twitter bootstrap along with validate.js and webmatrix for my IDE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <title>Weblio</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">       
</head>
<body>
    <!--navbar here-->

    <div class="navbar navTop">
        <div class="navbar-inner navbar-fixed-top">
            <a class="brand" href="/" ><i class="icon-phone-sign icon-2x"></i></a>              
            <ul class="nav">                   
                <!--<li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li> --> 
                <li>  
                    <form id="login" class="form-inline" method="post">
                        <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Email">
                        <input type="password" class="input-small" placeholder="Password">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox"> Remember me   
                        </label>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse signIn">Log in</button>
                    </form>
                </li>               
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--content-->
    <div id="register">
        <form id="registerform" method="POST" action=""  accept-charset='UTF-8'>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Register</legend> <br>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="20" value=""/> <br>
                <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" maxlength="20" value=""/> <br>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" maxlength="30" value=""/> <br>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" value=""/> <br>
                <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword"placeholder="Confirm Password" value=""/> <br>
                <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number" maxlength="10" value=""/> <br>
                <input type="date" name="birthday" id="birthday" placeholder="Birthday" value=""/> <br>
                <label id="legalConfirm" for="agree"><input type="hidden" name="agree" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" name="agree" id="agree" value="1" checked="checked" /> By clicking join you confirm that you accept our <a href="/privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a> and <a href="/terms.html">Terms of Service</a>.</label>
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="create" value="Join"/>
                <a href="/"><button type="button" class="btn">Cancel</button></a>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        </div>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../js/jquery.validation.min.js"></script>
        <script>
           $(document).ready(function () {

                var form = $("#registerform");

                var validator = form.validate({
                    rules: {
                        firstName: { 
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 4
                        },
                        lastName: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 4
                        },
                        email: {
                            required: true,
                            email: true,
                            minlength: 5
                       },
                        password: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 6
                        },
                        confirmPassword: {
                            required: true,
                            equalTo: '#password'
                        },
                        phoneNumber: {
                            required: true,
                            phoneUS: true
                        },
                        birthday: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        agree: {
                            required: true
                        }
                    }
                });

            });
        </script>



    <!--footer-->
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div id="footer"> Weblio &#169; 2013  | <a href="/about.html">About</a> |<a href="/faq.html">FAQ</a> | <a href="/privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="/terms.html">Terms of Use</a> | <a href="/contactUs.html">Contact Us</a>
        <div id="socialFooter"> 
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" title="Like us on Facebook."><i class="icon-facebook-sign icon-3x"></i></a>
            <a href="http://www.twitter.com/" target="_blank" title="Follow us on twitter."><i class="icon-twitter-sign icon-3x"></i></a>

        </div>
    </div>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I am getting this error in the webmatrix console.

Expected expression line 1, column 1 (which points to the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag.)

Thanks, any help would be great.

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that your local file also has access to the plugin here?: `../js/jquery.validation.min.js`

Comment: Yes, it is in a folder of the root

Comment: Sparky you were right I had to remove the path I was actually looking in the wrong folder, I don't how to upvote your comment, but if you answered it with that I will gladly upvote your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make absolutely sure the plugin is really located here:

```
../js/jquery.validation.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Leo: I copied and pasted your code into my html editor without modification(except linking to the google jquery libraries and it ran nicely in Firefox with an "html" file extension. I.E. 8 doesn't like it however and keeps giving me unspecific script errors. Which browser are you running it in?

Also some HTML house keeping is in order:
End input tags 
Remove the !DOCTYPE html (it should not hurt but is not needed)
The javascript should be in a head tag below the html tag and contain  TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT">

Comment: The site does show up. However, I am having trouble with the validation working in the js of the page. See if that works for you. If not and you have any clue that would be great.

Comment: I don't know if I was clear, when you input text that does not meet the requirements of the validation it should error, but that is not happening.